# An API service restricting me or my giant for loop too fast for my POST request?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, stream, shopify

I have a client who wants 8000 items pushed to his shopify store.

I made this code but I have a problem: Unless I limit the outgoing connections to roughly 1-2, the item posting responds with undefined and fail....my loop/post req might be too fast but all the methods I tried to slow it down with failed.

1. Here API restrictions set by them

> 2 calls per second, with room for a burst of 40 calls at once.

I'm using node.js and the ms sql plugin. The data from ms sql arrives fine via streams and is pushed to my array rowPush, then I loop through it(8000) to send out the post req via unicast.

```
sql.connect(userConfig, function(err) {
    if (err) {
    console.log("you done screwed up the dang connection to SQL " + err)
    };


 var request = new sql.Request();
 request.stream = true;
 request.verbose = true;

request.query('SELECT intProductID, Stock, strPurDesc, Vendor, Brand, intPurchasePrice, strBarCode FROM V_ProductList ORDER BY intProductID');

var rowPush = [];


//row is the object that returns  from MySQL database.

     request.on('row', function(row) {

        rowPush.push(row);

    });

    request.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('err occured ' + err);
    });

    request.on('done', function(returnValue) {


//my for loop for looping through every item in rowPush. 

    for (i =0; i < rowPush.length; i++ ) {

     var newProduct = {
             "product": {
                 "title": rowPush[i].strPurDesc,
                 "id": rowPush[i].intProductID,
                 "vendor": rowPush[i].Vendor,
                 "product_type": rowPush[i].Brand,  
 "variants": [
      {
        //"id": 1044399237,
        //"product_id": 1071559589,
        "inventory_management":"shopify",
        "inventory_quantity": rowPush[i].Stock,
        "barcode": rowPush[i].strBarCode,
        "price": rowPush[i].intPurchasePrice,
        "taxable" : true,

      }
        ]        
             }
         };          

         //console.log(JSON.stringify(newProduct));
         var sendNewItem = function (){
             unirest.post('https://5b848c9ca0e184f13140629d9c2d34ca:b8b14f71ad82a7d8f00520f8a4f5f571@teststoresrh.myshopify.com/admin/products.json')
//.header('Accept', 'application/json')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
.send(newProduct)
.end(function (response) {

  console.log(response.body);
});
         }
        if (rowPush[i].Vendor) {
    sendNewItem();
        };
          //sendNewItem();

    } 

    });
        console.log(rowPush[8210]);

    });
//});

sql.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("you done screwed up the dang connection to SQL " + err);
});
```

Comment: which methods you tryied to slowdown? does shopify allows for 'bundling' of data so to have only one (or few) post? is there any error message?

Comment: No error, just undefined if I try to send out more than two objects at a time. When it works I get a response back containingvmy uploaded response....looks like it does not like big data sets being pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now you are flooding the system. I've had luck with a few hundred items using a pattern like the one below. In a nutshell each product is only sent when the previous call returns. If you really need to throttle you can try the commented out setTimeout line instead of the one above it.

```
var https = require('https');

var cred = new Buffer(5b848c9ca0e184f13140629d9c2d34ca:b8b14f71ad82a7d8f00520f8a4f5f571").toString('base64');

var headers = {Authorization: "Basic "+cred, "Content-Type": "application/json"};

var options = {
  host: 'teststoresrh.myshopify.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/admin/products.json',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers
};

var rowPush = [];
// fill rowPush from sql


function sendProduct(){
  if(!rowPush.length) return;
  var row = rowPush.shift(); // FIFO
  var newProduct = (function(){
    // just like now but with row instead of rowPush[i];
  })();


// Setup the request.  The options parameter is
// the object we defined above.
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf-8');

  var responseString = '';

  res.on('data', function(data) {
    responseString += data;
    console.log(data);
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
    sendProduct();
    //setTimeout(sendProduct, 500);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  // TODO: handle error.
  console.log(e);
});

req.write(JSON.stringify(newProduct));
req.end();
} 
sendProduct();
```

Comment: Thanks, pushed me in the right direction. I ended up using the recursively calling the api call function with set timeout upon receiving response until every object in the array was removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a node module which can throttle function calls: [throttle-function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-function).